Copying differently contiguous arrays vs same contiguity arrays
I'm observing different speeds on different machines, but couldn't reason why. Please help me find the reason behind this and how one can handle this difference in performance-critical code - running different Python code on different hardware?
On timing this process:
arr2[...] = arr1 for different contiguities of arr1 and arr2, we get different timings.
On my local machine and server 1, it is faster to copy between arrays of same contiguity: C to C or F to F. The factor of speed-up is the same. (.027s vs .05s)
On server 2, it is faster to copy between different contiguities: C to F or F to C. The factor of speed-up is the same (.3s vs .5s)
server1 and server2 seem to be close in terms of the CPU spec:

numpy 1.21.5 local: 13th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-13700 Raptor Lake
numpy 1.19.2 server1: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2660 v3 @ 2.60GHz Haswell
numpy 1.17.3 server2: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-4640 v2 @ 2.20GHz Ivy Bridge

Timing code (EDITed):
import numpy as np
source = np.asfortranarray(np.random.rand(4913, 2971))
source[3000][150] = np.nan
srcmask = (source > .5) 
source[srcmask] = np.nan

cut = source[:, 0 : 300]
lc = np.zeros_like(cut, order='C')
lc2 = np.zeros_like(cut, order='F')
lc3 = np.zeros_like(cut.T, order='C')
lc4 = np.zeros_like(cut.T, order='F')

i = 0 

def trial1():
    global source, lc, i
    cut = source[:, i : i + 300]
    lc[...] = cut # F copied to C

def trial2():
    global source, lc2, i
    cut = source[:, i : i + 300]
    lc2[...] = cut # F copied to F

def trial3():
    global source, lc3, i
    cut = source[:, i : i + 300]
    lc3[...] = cut.T # C copied to C

def trial4():
    global source, lc4, i
    cut = source[:, i : i + 300]
    lc4[...] = cut.T # C copied to F

modes = ['F->C', 'FF', 'CC', 'C->F']
import timeit
from random import shuffle
all_trials = []
for ix in range(4):
    trials = list(enumerate([trial1, trial2, trial3, trial4]))
    shuffle(trials)
    all_trials.extend(trials)

mode_results = {mode: [] for mode in modes}
for ti, trial in all_trials:
    print('.', end='')
    i = 0 
    r_t = timeit.repeat(trial, repeat=9, number=100)
    mode_results[modes[ti]].append(sum(r_t) / len(r_t))

from pprint import pprint
pprint(mode_results)

EDIT: with the updated timing code above, I get these mean timings:

local same contig: .05s, different contig: .2s
serv2 same contig: .5s, different contig (4913, 2971): .4s, different contig (5000x3000): .3s


"it is faster to copy between arrays of same contiguity: C to C or F to F" This is generally the case. contiguous accesses are faster. I am not aware of any machine where non-contiguous accesses could be faster. At best they can be equally fast or a bit slower but not faster. Note that your benchmark is not very reliable since it is too short and the later calls are impacted by the first due to CPU caches. When it is run multiple times (eg. >3x), it seems to give relatively good results.

What you see can be a side effect of cache alignement trashing or something like that. It is hard to say without low-level CPU profiling information. On my machine I get the following means : 0.001842, 0.000966, 0.000948, 0.001871 (last run of 4 ones). Also please note that IvyBridge (13 years old) and Haswell (11 years old) are clearly obsolete nowadays.

One way to play with alignement is to add some padding. For example, to use np.random.rand(4919, 2971). You can find some information about cache trashing due to strided memory access in this post.

Thanks. I'm trying to figure out how to measure the contention for the same line or other low-level events as you suggested. I've tried running it as you suggested, and there does seem to be a difference based on alignment.
